# what is content type application/schema+json?

Tags: json, content-type

usually we set content in postman like `application/json`.

> what is the meaning of `application/schema+json` in content type, is it a way to
>   send multiple type of content?.

will it work if anyone send content type like `application/json+schema`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the meaning of `application/schema+json`?

`application/schema+json` is a media type for [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/). As of February 2020, it is not registered in [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). However, there's a [draft](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core.html) proposing it's registration:

> This document proposes a new media type `application/schema+json` to identify a JSON Schema for describing JSON data. [...]

A media type (formerly known as MIME type) is an identifier for file formats and format contents transmitted on the Internet and consists of a *type* and a *subtype* and can optionally define a *suffix* and *parameters*. The suffix is intended to specify the underlying structure of that media type.

In `application/schema+json`, the suffix is `+json`, indicates the underlying structure of that media type is a JSON document.

> Will it work if anyone send content type like `application/json+schema`?

I'm not aware of the existence of `application/json+schema`.

The correct media type is `application/schema+json`.

Comment: what if content type is application/json+schema?

Comment: @nitinverma I don't fully get your question.

Comment: i am confused between application/json+schema and application/schema+json.

Comment: @nitinverma `application/schema+json` is **not** the same thing as `application/json+schema` (which, by the way, I'm not aware of its existence).

Comment: @nitinverma Could you please provide any feedback to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JSON schema (something that describes the JSON) than it has application/schema+json content (media) type.

In one sentence - the JSON schema is a document (also in a JSON format) that describes your JSON. Pretty much like XSD for XMLs.

You can read about the spec [here](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-handrews-json-schema-00.html)

Comment: then what is the difference between application/schema+json vs application/json

Comment: application/json is for the regular JSON response... application/schema+json is for a special JSON schema that described json documents.... Different things spec-wise

Comment: is there any order need to follow or application/json+schema is also a valid content type

Comment: I think application/json+schema is enough if you want to access a json schema, and you don't need to specify both. But this is a point where you should try to use it with your tool as long as you understand which content type should be used for which types of requests...